# SQL Server 2012 - Insert into linked server table using openquery

Tags: sql-server, openquery

I have a linked server `Remoteserver` containing a table that holds file and folder names from a dir

When I am on the remote server I can run a built in procedure (`xp_dirtree`) and populate the 'files' table but what i need to do is to run a query from the local SQL server that does this:

1. Delete all records from the `[Files]` table on `Remoteserver`
2. Insert data that comes from the stored procedure:

   ```
   INSERT [Remoteserver].[dbo].[files] (subdirectory,depth,isfile)
      EXEC master.sys.xp_dirtree '\\Fileserver\DBBackup',1,1;
   ```
3. Select the 'subdirectory' column

I tried some things using openquery and i am able to select existing records  but unable to do the insert.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: "unable" - what it mean?

Comment: can you include the error message you're getting? it looks to me like your table name is missing a part. To be a valid remote query it should have four parts: Remoteserver.dbname.dbo.files for example

Comment: To be honest i am not quite sure about the right syntax to be used. I tried some variations of the openquery but i am sure thay are not right cause they didnt work :)...anyways the remote table name is as follows:[Remoteserver].[dbo].[files]....To clarify i dont need to pull the data into an existing table on the localserver...i Just need to display it on a web app so everything that needs to happen should happen remotely...the only thing that happens locally is the openquery that displays the data from the remoteserver 'files' table

Comment: show us what you've tried so far?

Comment: INSERT
OPENQUERY([Remoteserver], 
 '
  SELECT id,subdirectory,depth,isfile FROM [Remoteserver].[dbo].[files]
  
 ' 
 ) VALUES ('EXEC master.sys.xp_dirtree ''\\fileserver\DBBackup'',1,1')

Comment: and this one:    SELECT *
FROM OPENQUERY([Remoteserver], 
 '
 INSERT [Remoteserver].[dbo].[files] (subdirectory,depth,isfile)
 EXEC master.sys.xp_dirtree ''\\Fileserver\DBBackup'',1,1;
 SELECT subdirectory FROM [Remoteserver].[dbo].[files]
 
' )

Comment: what is the name of the database on Remoteserver?

Comment: we can call it [RemoteDB]...in my comment i say [Remoteserver].[dbo].[files] but please read it as [RemoteDB].[dbo].[files]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this

```
INSERT INTO OPENQUERY([Remoteserver]
    ,'SELECT subdirectory, depth, [file] FROM [RemoteDB].[dbo].[files]')
EXEC master.sys.xp_dirtree '\\fileserver\DBBackup', 1, 1;
```

OR

```
INSERT INTO OPENQUERY([Remoteserver]
    ,'SELECT subdirectory,depth, [file] FROM [RemoteDB].[dbo].[files]')
select * from OPENQUERY([another_server_name], 'master.sys.xp_dirtree ''\\fileserver\DBBackup\temp'', 1, 1');
```

But in general you do not need to use OPENQUERY at all if `Fileserver` and `Remoteserver` are accessible from the local machine.

```
INSERT INTO [Remoteserver].[RemoteDB].[dbo].[files] (subdirectory, depth, isfile)
   EXEC master.sys.xp_dirtree '\\Fileserver\DBBackup',1,1;
```

Comment: Thanks Andrey! the first query worked...I have a question about the other 2 methods you mentioned...The localserver and remoteserver are in 2 different networks separated by a firewall and also the fileserver exists in the same network as the remoteserver so if i choose to use either the 2nd or the third method would it be the localserver that is executing the 'dirtree' command against the fileserver?

Comment: not at all. if you are going to use `OPENQUERY` it might be any other server that is configured as linked server, but this may require the `MSDTC` to be enabled on each server (check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27726567/exec-sp-on-linked-server-and-put-that-in-temp-table/27731952#27731952)

Comment: thank you for the link...I have a followup question related to the above so asking it here.... I have 3 commands in my stored procedure - first one deletes all records from a table , second inserts new records and third pull those records but at the moment when the query runs the delete works but i dont get the records from the 3rd statement which is the "select" ....I am unable to post the code here because it is too long for the comment block.

Comment: it's bad. for now I can't help you without any information about the problem details. and for sure discussing your new problem here is definitely off-topic... you can try to figure it out or you could ask a new question...