# How pass data from SQL Server to mysql with the Microsoft tool SSIS 2005?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, ssis-2005

I'm using the Microsoft SSIS tool in version 2005 to generate ETL
I want to perform an ETL that takes care of passing data from a database I have in SQL Server to MySQL, and manages to migrate data from MySQL to SQL Server.

In the data target I only have these options.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to create a connection to to the MySQL server. 
https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/
Then, in control panel, administrative tools, you will need to create a system DSN.
Control Panel\System and Security\Administrative Tools\Data Source ODBC
If you develop SSIS on your computer not on the server, you need to install the driver there as well.
Once this is done, you need to select in the dataflow task the ODBC destination and apply the created DSN.

Comment: Hello thanks for the quick reply, but the problem that I do not have that destination of data, only has the options OLE DB, DataReader and SQL Server

Comment: How about adding the mysql server as a linked server? If you have the odbc connection you could do that. Then you can make the insert using openquery (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27854388/sql-server-2012-insert-into-linked-server-table-using-openquery). Or, try other BI tool as Pentaho.